# emacsclent -nw hangs

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs

As I use `emacsclient -nw -c` in a terminal e.g. `xterm -e emacsclient -nw -c`, emacs hangs when I resize horizontally (to the minimum allowed by the wm). I can't no longer launch any emacsclient window, thus I should kill the daemon to restart it.

It seems to be the `-nw` option that causes the issue.

Any clue to avoid this?

Comment: Can't you type `C-x C-c` in the resized window?

Comment: No keybinding seem to work.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Try testing if it happens with no init file, and if it does file a bug report.